# What are rubbery, conductive strips called on the sides of an LCD screen?

Tags: lcd

I found a component attached to a PCB inside one of my old $5 devices. There are pink, rubbery things attached to either side of the LCD that can bend and were firmly attached (glued?), and there are a lot of exposed conductive traces where the pink things were attached on the PCB.

I would like to know what these pink things are. Pictures are shown below.

[image: LCD]

The front side of the LCD ^

[image: LCD]

The back side of the LCD ^

[image: PCB]

The front side of the PCB. This is where the LCD is connected to. ^

[image: PCB]

The back side of the PCB ^

Again, I would like to know what the pink things are.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Often called Zebra strips (or Elastomeric connectors).  They have very thin vertical conductors that connect between flat PCB pads and things like LCD pads on glass.

Here is a link with a similar pink component.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastomeric_connector

Comment: The picture is exactly the same as what I have!

Comment: One a typical hobbyist would use! According to the Ahmed clock hoaxer!

Comment: A super tuto to repair the transparent conductive tape with the black conductive strip on the last picture https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l9_GDepbqMM&list=PLWmOqKOHj3hkS_fmLSKdAEBQa3bg2goty

Answer (score 17):

As  others note it's a "zebra connector" which conducts through the plane of the rubber but not across it (ie in the directions you'd expect for it to work).

The 'pitch' of the band s of conduction/non conduction are finer than the pitch of the contacts concerned so that short circuits are not formed between the contacts when the strip is moved "sideways".

Use an Ohm meter to measure resistance through the rubber between directly opposite points and then between points which are offset.
You will find that

- When the probes are opposite each other there will be a low resistance path between them.
- When the probes are offset by more than the thickness of the conductive bands that the resistance will be very high (or more :-) ).

This method allows ease of assembly, self alignment of the "connecter" - as long as the LCD contacts and PCB contacts are aligned the rubber strip alignment is non-crucial.

**Zebra strip inter-stripe pitch too large - shorting can occur**

█ = contact
▓ = zebra strip conductor
░ = zebra strip insulator

Alignment OK:

```
████  ████  ████  ████     
▓▓▓▓░░▓▓▓▓░░▓▓▓▓░░▓▓▓▓░  
████  ████  ████  ████
```

misaligned - shorts occur

```
████  ████  ████  ████      
▓░░▓▓▓▓░░▓▓▓▓░░▓▓▓▓░░▓▓▓  
████  ████  ████  ████
```

**Zebra strip inter-stripe pitch small wrt conductor pitch - shorting can not occur**

Alignment OK:

```
████  ████  ████  ████  
▓░▓░▓░▓░▓░▓░▓░▓░▓░▓░▓░▓    
████  ████  ████  ████
```

misaligned - shorting still cannot occur

```
████  ████  ████  ████
░▓░▓░▓░▓░▓░▓░▓░▓░▓░▓░▓░▓    
████  ████  ████  ████
```

[**See also this answer**](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/269256/3288)

Comment: I tried replacing ASCII-art with UTF8-art, slight improvement?

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick, nice work.  It's like going back to 1981 and squinting at a monochrome TV from 6 inches away.  Love it.

Comment: To add another layer of coolness, there's actually glue that does the same thing. Similar principle too. Glue your contacts and FFC together and you got ultralow profile solid connection with no soldering or connector necessary.

Comment: Interesting @Barleyman. Can you provide a link to one of glues?

Comment: @JeromyAdofo They are called "Anisotropic conductive adhesive", Anisotropic conductive film or Z-axis conductive adhesive. Mostly it's supplied as a tape to make application easier but you can buy liquid glue as well, which would be anisotropic conductive paste.