# What is this foam ribbon cable alternative in an old Norstar set?

Tags: ribbon-cable

I came upon some old Nortel phones and took apart one of the sidecars. The PCB is connected to the buttons and LCD displays using four sets of styrofoam-looking ribbon cables. They look like gross pink and black licorice candies. What is this sort of connector called? Just looking at one, you can't even tell that it's got multiple conductors. But I checked with a multimeter and it does. They adhere rather poorly to the PCB (maybe because the phone is about 18 years old).

[image: Back of PCB]

[image: The Meridian M7324 sidecar and a phone]

Comment: google `zebra strip`

Comment: @jsotola beat me by 30s!

Comment: it is a multi-conductor strip .... it is not designed to adhere ... it only has to touch

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are rubbery, conductive strips called on the sides of an LCD screen?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/157647/what-are-rubbery-conductive-strips-called-on-the-sides-of-an-lcd-screen)

Comment: correct term is `elastomeric connector` .... few here ... https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=p2380057.m570.l1313.TR0.TRC0.H0.XElastomeric+connector.TRS0&_nkw=Elastomeric+connector&_sacat=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called an [Elastomeric Connector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastomeric_connector).  They are made with alternating insulating/conductive regions, side-to-side, so that they conduct only in the vertical direction.

Matching pads on the board contact the conductive parts of the elastomeric block.  Compressing the block between the boards compresses the surface to the contacts on the boards and makes a board-to-board connection.

The plastic shell makes sure that the connector does not buckle when the block is compressed.

[image: connectors]

(From http://www.zaxisconnector.com/images/Elastomeric-Connector-Collage-Compressed.jpg)