# How to reattach LCD to pcb that has power but no data?

Tags: pcb, soldering, lcd, pins, remote-control

Where do the lcd data connectors actually attach?

I have been researching to attach lcd to pcb but every example I find has notiable pins from thw lcd.

I can see the pins on the board but how do they attach?

[image]

Comment: Most likely it is zebra strip connection between the PCB and the LCD glass: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/157647/what-are-rubbery-conductive-strips-called-on-the-sides-of-an-lcd-screen/269847#269847

Comment: The normal for displays (LCD/OLED/TFT) with a "chip on glass" (COG) driver is that they come with a flexible flat cable (FFC), which you then connect to the PCB with a "FFC connector". There are countless of different versions of this. What's used in your case, I can't tell from the picture.

Answer (score 0):

From the photo, all I see are PCB pads for the LCD, not pins. My guess is the LCD would easily lift off the PCB if you tried this. This can be confusing if you were expecting pins or any sort of connector. If this is the case, then the pins are on the LCD and are the conductive/crush type (as MarkU said) that make contact with the PCB pads using pressure from the frame or enclosure. Try pulling it off and press on the LCD pins, it should crush like rubber. This is the most economical method since it avoids the cost of connectors on both ends.

Comment: The zebra strips usually connect PCB pads to the optically transparent segment pads on the underside of the front layer of the LCD glass which overhangs the rest of the assembly.