# How can I re-assemble this cheap scale's LCD display?

Tags: connector, lcd, repair, display, mechanical-assembly

I had to disassemble a cheap kitchen scale for cleaning after it stopped working because of fluids. To my surprise I found the LCD does not seem to have a physical connection, but some sort of magnetic link to the board.

The LCD came with a rubber strip and it has some pins in the crystal.

Any tips? Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: There's no magnets involved, just pressure. That connector is called an elastomeric connector, or colloquially a zebra strip (yours isn't, but most of them seem to be striped, like a zebra).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are rubbery, conductive strips called on the sides of an LCD screen?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/157647/what-are-rubbery-conductive-strips-called-on-the-sides-of-an-lcd-screen)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The rubber strip has many parallel conducting wires across it, and will connect a set of contacts on the PCB to a set of contacts on the LCD display.

Place it properly between the PCB and the display and it should work (it can be a bit fiddly; test before further reassembly; press LCD display down carefully if necessary). The LCD display and PCB will eventually be kept in place and pressed together by the enclosure.

Also see [What are rubbery, conductive strips called on the sides of an LCD screen?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/157647/what-are-rubbery-conductive-strips-called-on-the-sides-of-an-lcd-screen) and the [Wikipedia article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastomeric_connector).

Comment: Ended up using the casing of the display to properly align it. Otherwise it was impossible. Now have a perfectly working (and clean) scale again!